# How to remove the lines after Texture Mapping?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

How can I remove the lines at this sphere(that is the sun), after I used Texture mapping??

I don't know what is happening, why are those lines appearing? I know that when we used Texture over an object in the class with the professor it didn't showed us those lines.

Here is the code for the sun:

```
var sun, sunGeo, sunMat;
sunGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2300,32,32);

var suntexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/sun1.jpg');

suntexture.anisotropy = 8;
sunMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
ambient: 0x333333,
    side: THREE.BackSide,
map: suntexture, 
emissive: 0xffffff
});

sun = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeo, sunMat);
scene.add(sun);
```

[image: The sun]

With those lines it looks awful.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have wireframe turned on.

Add "wireframe: false" in the material declaration, or explicitly set it to false ("sunMat.wireframe = false;") elsewhere before drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CanvasRenderer? It sometimes renders like that, and I believe it's just because CanvasRenderer has various limitations/drawbacks which you might or might not be able to work around. Consider using WebGLRenderer.